# MYSQL Query fail to select possible result

Tags: mysql

I want to get all emp_ids of employees which is manager_id equal to login user_id. But why this query show only first result of the column. I could not able to find the problem.

```
            $userID=$_SESSION['userID'];

            var_dump($userID);

            $result1 =  mysql_query("SELECT emp_id FROM employee where manager_id='$userID' ORDER BY emp_id");
            $array = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
            $id1=$array['emp_id'];
```

---

Please help !

Comment: Mysql extensions have been removed in PHP 7 so Please stop using mysql_* functions. Consider using Mysqli_* functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should loop over the result

and eg: you can store all the empID in an array

```
$cnt = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    echo "ID: " . $row[0] ;  
    $myArrayOfEmpID[$cnt] = $row[0];
    $cnt++;
}
```

instead you only  set

```
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
 $id1=$array['emp_id'];
```

Comment: How can I get value into a variable instead of printf?

Comment: I want to get this value into a variable, instead of echo. How can I get it?

Comment: You mean in an array ?

Comment: Yep, How can I assign this array into a variable?

Comment: use  $myArrayOfEmpID[$cnt] = $row[0]; instead  myArrayOfEmpID[$cnt] = $row[0];